# How to block the commands in DMs?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I realized that, on my bot, the commands can be executed in directs messages.
I wanna know how to block them in this type of channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the channel is a [DMChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel):

```
if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) //do not execute
else //execute
```

With that said: I see you are new in StackOverflow, but keep in mind that you should always try and explain what you tried to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using this as the first part of your command:
`if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;`